# Can "const char[18]* be changed to an entity of type LPCWSTR(C++)?

Tags: c++, windows, graphics, drawing

I am writing a program in C++, and I had an unexpected error. I am trying to draw to a window, and I get the errors "Error (active) E0513   a value of type "const char *" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "LPCWSTR"". I apologize if this is a bad question, but do you know if there is a way to convert a type LPCWSTR to a string or char? This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

LRESULT CALLBACK window_callback(HWND hand, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    return DefWindowProc(hand, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}


int WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd)  {
    //Creating a Class for the window
    WNDCLASS window_class = {};
    window_class.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    //The next line is the one causing the error.
    window_class.lpszClassName = "Game Window Class";
    window_class.lpfnWndProc = window_callback;
    
}
```

Comment: Why not just use a wide string literal: `window_class.lpszClassName = L"Game Window Class";`? `LPCWSTR` is short for "long pointer to constant wide string" i.e. `wchar_t const*` and converting between `char const*` and `wchar_t const*` can be a bit tricky, so avoiding having to add logic by simply using a wide string literal is preferable in general.

Comment: The way you're supposed to do it in Windows is with the `_T` macro: `_T("Game Window Class")`, but in practice it's more clutter than actually useful.

Comment: If you want you can also use std::wstring to store your string and then use std::wstring::c_str() to get an LPCWSTR compatible pointer. But the L prefix is the most easy to use. _T is possible to, that will ensure that the string matches the unicode settings of your project (so either char* or wchar_t*)